# Office 2019 - Preview pane is not working for Excel files in protected view

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-explorer

I faced a problem with Excel files and preview pane in Explorer. When I select an Excel file that is stored locally, it shows the preview as expected. However, when I select a file from a network share, the preview pane stays white/empty (no error messages either).

I checked the settings already in Explorer and Excel, that I found online. I found out that the problem is only present with files, which have protected view enabled. As soon as I open the file and click the warning message to open the file for editing, it makes the preview work for that single file. And if I disable protected view completely, all Excel files have their previews as expected. Word seems to be not affected by this, as I have preview with protected mode as well.

Does someone know why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: I dont have any specific experience with this, but it might help to look into making your network drive a trusted source/site/location. This can be either a Windows setting, or perhaps even an app specific setting inside of Excel and Word. The distinction between how Excel and Word handles potentially dangerous files may be related to individual file capabilities and associated risks.